# C# Form gradual fade

Tags: c#, winforms, opacity

All I want to do is to display the form with 100 opacity then after X time it starts to fade until 0.0 opacity, I have the algorithm but I don't know where to implement it as if I use it in Form_Load the Forms already shows up with the final opacity, as well as after InitializeComponent();

```
this.Opacity = 1.0;

for (float i = 1.0f; i >= 0.0f; i -= 0.1f)
{
    this.Opacity = i;
    Thread.Sleep(150);
}
```

Comment: Consider using WPF instead; WinForms wasn't really made for that sort of thing...

Comment: i would avoid sleeping.

Comment: The sleeping is just me trying to make the form show before doing the function

Comment: And it has a direct relationship to how fast the form fades, but it will freeze the UI thread until it's done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Shown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx), which happens only once after the Form loads, or, if you want it to happen every time the form gets Focus, use the [Activated Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated.aspx).

In Form1.cs:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Opacity = 1.0;

    for (float i = 1.0f; i >= 0.0f; i -= 0.1f)
    {
        this.Opacity = i;
        Thread.Sleep(150);
    }
}
```

In Form1.Designer.cs:

```
this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Shown);
```

If you want to make the form invisible but the controls remain visible, you can use the [TransparencyKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey.aspx) property:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Choose some obscure background that no other controls will have
    this.BackColor = Color.Red;
    this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;
}
```

Comment: For some weird reason when it's fading out the text have a transparente background like I can see through the image and no text at all

Comment: That's what the opacity does...what did you want it to do?

Comment: I updated with an example of making the form transparent but not the controls. Not sure if there's a way to do that gradually or not, though...